# ¿Como usar jquery-turboLinks?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Actualmente tengo un problema ya que jquery no esta trabajando correctamente en mi proyecto de ruby on rails y cuando investigue me di cuenta que el document.ready no funciona de buena manera en dicho framework, asi que decidi bajarme el parche que seria  `jquery-turboLinks`, pero una vez que lo instale y todo eso. me salio este error.

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Inicio#index 

    Showing /home/david/Escritorio/prueba_ruby/app/views/inicio/index.html.erb where line #13 raised:

    SyntaxError: [stdin]:9:9: unexpected or

    Rails.root: /home/david/Escritorio/prueba_ruby
```

La linea que me marca #13 es esta linea de codigo:

```
<%= image_tag("1.jpg", :class=>"cloud9-item" ) %
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un error, te falta un `>` al final:

```
<%= image_tag("1.jpg", :class=>"cloud9-item" ) %>
                                                ^
```

En cuanto al uso de **turbolinks**, cambia este código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // código
});
```

por este otro:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  // código
});
```

Puedes ver el detalle en las [guías de rails (en inglés)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks).

Comment: ^  como agregas ese caracter ? Gerry que no es igual a ˆ

Comment: @elporfirio Simplemente agregué una nueva línea y le puse espacios hasta llegar a la posición adecuada, luego simplemente utilicé _`SHIFT` + tecla `^ [`_ (tengo teclado en español, con mac). Para verlo dale clic en editar a mi respuesta y verás el formato original.